# How to rename AWS Lambda Function Name without changing its Function URL with SAM?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam

I am working with the following AWS SAM Template.

```
Resources:
  PaymentFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: payment_function
      CodeUri: PaymentFunction/
      Description: 'A lambda function to do a payment'
      ...
      ...
      ...
      FunctionUrlConfig:
        AuthType: NONE
        Cors:
          AllowOrigins:
            - "*"
          AllowHeaders:
            - "*"
          AllowMethods:
            - "*"

Outputs:
  PaymentFunctionUrl:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt: PaymentFunctionUrl.FunctionUrl
```

When I deploy this function with **aws deploy** command. I get the following function url

```
https://{random_string}.lambda-url.{aws_region}.on.aws/
```

whenever I change the LogicalResourceId i.e. **PaymentFunction** or actual function name i.e. **payment_function**, it creates a new **{random_string}**. that means a new function URL.
Is it possible to change the function_name without changing function URL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. The [CFN docs for the FunctionName property of an AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-functionname) clearly states that the updating of the name requires `Replacement` of the resource. This means that the old resource will be deleted and a new resource will be created with a new function URL.

Changing the `LogicalResourceId` of any cfn resource will automatically create a new resource in your AWS account and delete the old one. For Lambda functions, this always results in a different function URL.

If you want to invoke lambdas using URLs that you have more control over (and can easily change the lambda function that gets executed for each path), have a look at [the REST API of the Amazon API Gateway service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html).

Comment: Ok! Thanks I will look into api gateway